# How to apply the concepts of String methods in python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, lowercase

In the below-mentioned code I have added user_input.lower() but still, this code does not give expected output for input as W, M or S, can someone explain me why, Am I using string methods incorrectly in python?

```
# Password Generator
import random
import string

print('----------------PASSWORD GENERATOR-------------------')

print('''We will help you to generate 3 types of passwords
1. Weak passwords : It will consist 4 alphabets.
2. Moderate passwords: It will consist 7 alphanumeric characters.
3. Strong Passwords : It will consist 10 alphanumeric and symbol     
characters.''')


while True:
        user_input = input('''
    What type of password you need?
    Enter "W" for weak password
    Enter "M" for moderate password
    Enter "S" for strong password\n''')

    # To reduce chances of error if user gives command in upper or lower case.
       user_input.lower()


        if user_input is 'w':
            alphabet = string.ascii_letters # string.digits + string.punctuation
            password = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(4))
            print(password)
            break

        elif user_input is 'm':
            alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits # string.punctuation
            password = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(7))
            print(password)
            break

        elif user_input is 's':
            alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
            password = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))
            print(password)
            break

        else:
            print('Please enter a valid choice')
```

Comment: You'd have to clarify what exactly you expect, but string.lower returns a new string. It doesn't change the string you're modifying. Strings are immutable. You can't change them once created.

Also you want == not is. Is checks for object identity not equality. 's' == 's' is True, 's' is 's' is False.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you use ".lower()" it isn't actually saving the output to the variable. So for it to be saved in the variable you will have to do "user_input = user_input.lower()".

Comment: To expand on this, in place methods in python always return None,  where as non-inplace (string methods) changes return the value. ie a = a.append(1) will return None, as lists are changed in place. b = b.lower() will return the value of b.lower() as it applies to the entire string.